# $SRCROOT not recognized in shell script attached to XCode project

Tags: xcode, shell

Trying to run a simple script attached to my xcode project as follows...

```
if [ -d '$HOME/data' ]; 
then
  cd "$HOME/data/"
  rsync -t *.plist '$SRCROOT/data/'
fi

exit 0
```

The script seems to run fine if I run it outside of XCode but when running from XCode I'm getting the following error...

```
line 2: SRCROOT: command not found
```

Seems the SRCROOT variable isn't detectable in the script but my understanding was that this is one of the environment variables that should be passed and accessible to the script.  Any thought?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out this was my fault.  The script was actually not being called at all.  In XCode I was referring to the path of the script using...

```
"./$(SRCROOT)/myScript.sh"
```

Switching it to...

```
"$SRCROOT/myScript.sh"
```

Corrected the problem and indeed I can access $SRCROOT from my script now.

Comment: does this mean if you run a shell script from NStask, you can access variables like $PROJECT_FILE_PATH, etc from your shell scripts on the deployed app's machine?  it would be great to use the resource bundle variables in bash!

Comment: That does sound like it would be pretty cool.  Unfortunately I have never tried something like that.

Comment: I hit this same issue. When you add an "input file", directly below the Run Script text area, the default path name is `$(SRCROOT)/myfile`. But per this answer you should use `$SRCROOT`. +1